# utilizing "isalpha" or "startswith" and/or troubleshooting "list index out of range error"

Tags: python, csv, svg, beautifulsoup

I'm a newbie in all facets (SO, python, beautifulsoup, etc), so bear with me please.

I am trying to create a variety of maps with different types of data following a tutorial found at flowingdata.com (how to make a US county thematic map using free tools).

I can duplicate the tutorial without error so no version issues I can speak of (I'm using Python 2.7.5 and BeautifulSoup 4.3.1 on Mac OS 10.8).  I would like to use (more detailed) state-county maps and colorize them with different data.  I have the maps (svg) and data (csv) in appropriate files.  Here is the script I am currently running:

```
import csv
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

totpop = {}
reader = csv.reader(open('datafile.csv', 'rU'), delimiter=",")
for row in reader:
    try:
        id = row[0]
        pop = float( row[1].strip() )
        totpop[id] = pop
    except:
        pass

svg = open('mapfile.svg', 'r').read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(svg, selfClosingTags=['defs', 'sodipodi:namedview', 'path'])

paths = soup.findAll('path')

colors = ["#F1EEF6", "#D4B9DA", "#C994C7", "#DF65B0", "#DD1C77", "#980043"]

path_style = 'fill-rule:nonzero; stroke: #ffffff; stroke-width: 5; stroke-opacity: 1; fill: '

# Colorize based on data
for p in paths:

        try:
            pop = totpop[p['id']]
        except:
            continue

        if pop > 750000:
            color_class = 6
        elif pop > 500000:
            color_class = 5
        elif pop > 250000:
            color_class = 4
        elif pop > 125000:
            color_class = 3
        elif pop > 75000:
            color_class = 2
        elif pop > 25000:
            color_class = 1
        else:
            color_class = 0

        color = colors[color_class]
        p['style'] = path_style + color


print soup.prettify()
```

And I'm getting the following error:

> File "scriptname.py", line 54, in 
>      color = colors[color_class]
>   IndexError: list index out of range

("line 54" may not match because I removed some comment lines in the sample code)

Regarding the svg file, it has both paths and groups of paths (the groups of paths are counties comprised of multiple paths).  Single path counties have the county name as the "id." Multi-path counties have the county name as the group "id" however the nested paths have numeric ids.  I want the style to be applied to either the path or group that matches the county name in the data file (I'm fully aware the sample code does not deal with groups right now).  To test, I ran the script on a sample svg that had only paths (no groups) and it worked brilliantly...so I know something is right.  I think the issue is with the groups and/or the paths (within the groups) with numeric ids.

How do I get around the error?  I tried to remove the groups and change all the multi-path ids to the same thing...that didn't work either.  Do the numeric ids cause problems if they're not explicitly ignored?

I'm wondering if I can run a script that either singles out the paths and/or groups that have names (no numbers/digits) using some sort of "isalpha" tool or "startswith" (any letter) to avoid the index error.

I hope that provides enough information.

Here is a link to one of the [svg maps](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/54/Map_of_North_Carolina_highlighting_Wake_County.svg)  (I have stripped the clippath and state_outline from my working file)  And here is a link to the corresponding [datafile](http://www.theadventureelement.com/images/NCpop2010.csv)

If you test the files, you may have viewbox issues but I have sorted that out separately.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Your `colors` list only has elements from 0 to 5 and you're trying to index #6...

Comment: btw, in general, to deal with cases like this: in your console, `import pdb: pdb.pm()` after the point of failure will drop you back into the code that failed, so you can see what the list and index look like...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it, you're probably assuming in your following array:

`colors = ["#F1EEF6", "#D4B9DA", "#C994C7", "#DF65B0", "#DD1C77", "#980043"]`

that the elements here are indexed as 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6. The index is actually going to begin with 0 and not 1. So "#F1EEF6" is actually element 0 and the last element ("#980043") is number 5 in your array. In your `if pop` statements, you'll need to make this adjustment.

Also, you'll need to change the `else` statement to set your `color_class` to something you can use to determine whether you should attempt to grab a valid color or not. I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
else:
    color_class = null

if color_class != null
    color = colors[color_class]
    p['style'] = path_style + color
```

I'm not familiar with the Python syntax so there may be an error in there but hopefully you get the idea I'm trying to show here.

Comment: thanks @Ant for the quick response.  That has resolved my issue.  I actually knew the color array started with 0 not 1, I just failed to amend the script when I changed the color array for a different dataset.